# Convert a materialized view into a table in Oracle 11g?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, materialized-views

I am running Oracle 11g and SQL Developer on the client. I have a materialized view that I would like to convert into an ordinary table. How can that be done?

The only way I have come up with is to create a table with the same structure, export the data from the MV and import it to the table. However to do that I would have to manually create all the fields (30+) for the table to match those in the MV. So I figured there must be a better solution?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

simple
[DROP MATERIALIZED VIEW .. PRESERVE TABLE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_8019.htm) will do it